# Value of 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in response is '' which must be 'true'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redux, netlify

Have my backend deployed to heroku and my frontend deployed to netlify. I can't get past the landing page and login page on my netlify app link, even though my site worked fine before trying to get it deployed. I am seeing this console error several times when I try to login to my app on netlify and fail to do so:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://photo-sharer-backend.herokuapp.com/api/v1/get_current_user' from origin 'https://photo-sharer-kkirby16.netlify.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
photo-sharer-backend.herokuapp.com/api/v1/get_current_user:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
```

Tried putting `mode: "no-cors"` in my fetch requests.

Tried putting `"Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true` in headers object of all my fetch requests.

Tried putting `config.hosts.clear` in the module within config/application.rb

Still haven't fixed this error with trying those things. There is also not much online for this. From something I saw however it seems I may need to change something on the backend so that the response has the header, rather than focusing on frontend changes. Possibly I need to change my cors.rb file? Does anyone have ideas how I can fix this error?

First time trying to deploy a site and I would really appreciate any help.

Also, here is my cors.rb file:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins "https://photo-sharer-kkirby16.netlify.app"

    resource "*",
             headers: :any,
             methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head],
             credentials: false
  end
end
```

Comment: The header has to be in the _reponse_, not the _request_. You can see the issue in cors.rb, you have `credentials: false` instead of `true`

Comment: @CherryDT Thanks, yeah I just thought of that right before reading this and changed `credentials: false` to `credentials: true` and that got rid of that error and now I can at least login to my site.

Comment: @CherryDT So I don't see the above error anymore which is good. Were you also thinking I needed to add more to my cors.rb, such as more in the `headers:` part of it? Or just that small credentials change?

Comment: I meant just that.

Comment: @CherryDT Okay cool, thanks. So now I can login to my site and logout, but can't really do anything else and am seeing this console error I'd seen earlier on: 

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
photo-sharer-kkirby16.netlify.app/:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input`

Have you seen this error before?

Comment: That is a new question.